# ios 6 : NSLayoutConstraint issue in iphone 5.1 simulator

Tags: ios

I am getting an error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

when I am trying to run my application in iPhone 5.1 simulator. Iam setting the NSLayoutConstraint for running the project in both 3.5 inch and 4 inch display. If the NSLayoutConstraint is not supporting for iPhone 5.1 simulator, how can I adjust the frames in 3.5 inch and 4 inch display ?

Comment: I guess the autoresizing height mask is the best choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have checked autoLayout feature in xcode4.5 while designing your xibs files then you will not able to support iOS 5, what you have you have to do is uncheck autolayout from each and every xib file and use autoresize feature for supporting the 4.0inch screen.
 You can also try this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Thanks. Now how can i set auto resizing property programmatically ?

Comment: you can set it through xib using Autosizing property, you just have to adjust the height of your scroll content.

Comment: I need to set Autosizing property through code and how can i do this for tabbar ?

Comment: you cannot do this tabbar as default tabbar has to be of same height i.e.49px in both 3.4 and 4.0 inch screen, instead of this try to Autosize your viewcontroller.

Comment: ok.. but I am doing like, adding buttons having image on the tabbar. So i need to adjust the tabbar also. and my button height is only 47px. Or is there any other way to customize tabbar with my own image ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use AutoLayout (i.e. NSLayoutConstraint) in iOS 5.1 because it is new to iOS 6. For all your IB files, make sure that "Use Autolayout" is not checked.